# Issue with SplashScreen java

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen

I need help with my code.

I'm having problem to start my SplashScreen of my Java application.
The principal class (bolaoJFrame) that extends `JFrame` and calls a screen logon that extends  `JDialog`. After the validation of user, the SplashScreen is created but don't appears. 
What am I doing wrong?

The SplashScreen should appear after the validation to show a `JProgressBar` while the loading of class principal does not finish.

This is the metodo main of pricipal class:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(bolaoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(bolaoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(bolaoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(bolaoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>


    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            bolaoJFrame principal= new bolaoJFrame();
            principal.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            login = new loginJDialog(principal, true);
            if(newUser==true){
                CardLayout cards = (CardLayout)(principal.jpPrincipal.getLayout());
                cards.show(principal.jpPrincipal, "cadastro");
            }else{
                if(Usuario.userCriado==0){
                    System.exit(0);
                }else{

                    Splash telaSplash =new Splash(null);
                    telaSplash.setVisible(true);

                    CardLayout cards = (CardLayout)(principal.jpPrincipal.getLayout());
                    cards.show(principal.jpPrincipal, "apostas");
                    principal.jLabel1.setText("Bem vindo " + user.getUsername());
                    principal.jLabel4.setIcon(new Util().dimencionaImagem(user.getFoto(),80));

                    HoraDoSistema.start(principal.retomaHora(),principal.lbRelagio);
                    principal.montaCards();
                    PanelRanking pr = new PanelRanking(10, 1, user.getUserCod());

                    principal.jpRanking.add(pr,"1");
                    if(pr.getPosUser()>0){
                       principal.lbRankingInfo.setText("Sua posição atual é " + pr.getPosUser() + "º" ); 
                    }
                    if(pr.getPontuacaoUser()>0){
                       principal.lbPontuacaoInfo.setText("Você fez " + pr.getPontuacaoUser()+ " pontos" ); 
                    }                        
                    principal.lbNext.requestFocus();


                    principal.verificaDisponibilidad();
                }
            }


          principal.setVisible(true); 




        }
    });
}
```

SplashScreen Class:

```
public Splash(JFrame owner) {
    //super(owner);
    setLayout(null);
    Util.centralizarJanela(this, 521, 335);
    inicialize();
}



public void inicialize(){
    JLabel fundo = new JLabel();
    //fundo.setLocation(new Point(0,0));
    fundo.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Principal/splash.png")));
    fundo.setSize(521, 315);
    add(fundo);

    barraDeProgresso= new JProgressBar();
    barraDeProgresso.setBackground(Color.red);
    barraDeProgresso.setBounds(0, 315, 521, 20);
    barraDeProgresso.setStringPainted(true);
    add(barraDeProgresso);
}

public void setValorBarraDeProgresso(int progresso){
    barraDeProgresso.setValue(progresso);
}

public int getValorBarraDeProgresso(){
    return barraDeProgresso.getValue();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Refrain from use `null` layouts. You do not control the factors that affect the size requirements/decisions for components that will change their sizes on different platforms/os's

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is `setLayout(null);`, my second guess is you're not actually applying a size or location to the `Splash` window

Normally, something like `pack()` and `setLocationRelativeTo(bolaoJFrame)` would be what you want, but because you decided to discard the layout manager, `pack` will no longer help you...

**Updated...**

So the basic workflow is something like...

```
bolaoJFrame principal= new bolaoJFrame();
principal.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

//...
Splash telaSplash =new Splash(null);
telaSplash.setVisible(true);
//..

principal.setVisible(true);
```

The problem with this, is the windows are likely to appear (almost) simultaneously as there is no delay between the `setVisible` commands.

You could use a `javax.swing.Timer` to insert a short delay between making the splash screen visible and the `principal`

While not possible to determine from your code snippet, it's also possible you are blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, prevent any new events from processing and preventing the windows from been shown

Comment: Guys thank you for the help, but in reality the SplashScreen appears but only when the bolaoJFrame gains the visibility too.
If you notice, the SplashScreen is created by bolaoJFrame before gaining the visibility.

The process is:
bolaoJFrame is created >> logon Screen is created by bolaoJFrame >> SplashScreen is created by bolaoJFrame

Comment: Why would it happen any other way?  Until you exit the method, the EDT can't process all the new events to get your UI up to speed

Comment: Man I don't understand. You can explain better?